# Flutter Error:-RenderBox and scroll extent is negative and how to hide widget if there is no video?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Getting these two errors when user enters and have no videos uploaded yet and after uploading there is no such error. And how can I hide this widget if there is no video. Pls help me out to hide this widget and get away from this error.

```
1:- RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#18b64 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

2:-  SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.
```

The code in which error is showing:-

```
    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: myvideos,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot){
                          if(!snapshot.hasData){
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }if(snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty){
                            return Container();
                          }

                          return GridView.builder(
                              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                                childAspectRatio: 2/2,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                DocumentSnapshot video = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                                return Container(
                                  height: 150,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(

                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,offset: Offset(2,2),spreadRadius: 2,blurRadius: 5
                                      )
                                    ],
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 150,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded,size: 60,color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: NetworkImage(video.data()['previewimage'],), fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      //  child: Image(image: NetworkImage(video.data()['previewimage'],), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                      //  Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded,color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),)

                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              );
                          },
                        ),

                    ),
```

Getting videos from here:- How can I hide this? If there is no video yet.

```
        myvideos = videoscollection.where('uid',isEqualTo:     widget.currentUser.uid).get();
```

Comment: You probably just need another `if` saying `if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) return Container();`

Comment: where to add this? because Container widget is taking height before I am calling myvideos.

Comment: Add it after your `if(!snapshot.hasData){` and before the `return GridView.builder(`.

Comment: na.. no difference made. Still taking space of the container, because it has been called at very first which takes height:150.

Comment: How is that even possible unless your `snapshot.data.docs` is not empty. update your question with new code.

Comment: yeah I don't know, surprisingly... I can share any desk if it is ok  with you. even I don't get it why It is taking space.

Comment: updated. pls check.

Comment: so, which element is actually taking the extra space ? try putting `color` to your containers and tell me which one is taking space.

Comment: the very first container from where it begins. child:Container(height:150 .

Comment: oh. in that case, that's expected, just use the `FutureBuilder` as your first Widget and then bring the first `Container` inside and make it the parent of `GridView.builder`.

Comment: finally.. worked.. thanks for your time and patience..